# Bad theme code - can you find the error?

Tags: themes, code

This is what I have, and I need each of these blocks to pull the link, title of each blog post, and featured image they're supposed pull. Do you see the error?

```
<div class="home-featured-block">
     <?php
        $featured_block=$profitmag_settings['featured_block_one'];
        $no_of_block=$profitmag_settings['no_of_block_one'];                    
        $query1=new WP_Query( 'cat='.$featured_block.'&posts_per_page='.$no_of_block );
        if( $query1->have_posts() ):
            $cat_name = get_cat_name( $featured_block );                       
    ?>
            <h2 class="block-title"><span class="bordertitle-red"></span><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h2>
            <div class="feature-post-wrap clearfix">
    <?php
        $count = 0;
            while( $query1->have_posts() ):
                $query1->the_post();
            $count++;
    ?>
                <div class="featured-post clearfix">
                    <figure class="post-thumb clearfix">
                        <?php
                            if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                                $post_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'three-col-thumb' );
                        ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $post_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></a>
                        <?php
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-desc clearfix">
                        <h3 class="feature-main-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="post-date feature-main-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php echo get_the_date( 'F d, Y') ; ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php
    if($count % 3 == 0) echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a lot of things that could be considered "an error." What error are you trying to track down? What have you already done in attempts to narrow things down?

Comment: @EAMann: anything you see would be beneficial. What I'm trying to do, though, is get it to pull my blog post and assign it as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm just going to list things out as I go through. Some of what follows is stylistic feedback, some is security related, some is functional:

```
<div class="home-featured-block"> 
    <?php
        $featured_block=$profitmag_settings['featured_block_one'];
        $no_of_block=$profitmag_settings['no_of_block_one'];
```

I don't know what the `$profitmag_settings` variable looks like, but either of these parameters could be unset. Instead of just assuming they exist, you need to provide a default. For example, `$featured_block = isset( $profitmag_settings['featured_block_one'] ? $profitmag_settigs['featured_block_one'] : 'default';`.

```
        $query1=new WP_Query( 'cat='.$featured_block.'&posts_per_page='.$no_of_block );
```

Seeing that these values are being passed into a query bothers me. String concatenation is only OK if you're sanitizing values before passing them along. So instead of just a straight-up concatentation, I'd wrap in sanitization functions. For example: ... `'&posts_per_page=' . absint( $no_of_block ) );`

```
        if( $query1->have_posts() ):
            $cat_name = get_cat_name( $featured_block );                       
    ?>
           <h2 class="block-title"><span class="bordertitle-red"></span><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h2>
```

Before using `$cat_name`, you need to first make sure it exists (what if no category exists with the specified ID?). You also need to, again, sanitize things before outputting on the page: `<?php echo esc_html( $cat_name ); ?>`.

```
            <div class="feature-post-wrap clearfix">
            <?php
            $count = 0;
            while( $query1->have_posts() ):
                $query1->the_post();
                $count++; ?>
                <div class="featured-post clearfix">
                    <figure class="post-thumb clearfix">
                        <?php
                        if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                            $post_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'three-col-thumb' );
                        ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $post_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></a>
```

Again, you need to be escaping things before echoing to the page. `echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() )` is preferred over just `the_permalink()` for security purposes, for example. And you need to verify that the `$post_thumb` returned is actually what you expected before you use it, following by escaping the output as you print it.

```
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-desc clearfix">
                        <h3 class="feature-main-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="post-date feature-main-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php echo get_the_date( 'F d, Y') ; ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                if($count % 3 == 0) echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only other feedback I can provide is a question: If this isn't doing what you expect it to, then what *is* it doing. On the surface, the code itself looks functionally correct. The only other things that could be an issue is how you're setting up your categories and using them to identify `$featured_block`. I'd check first of all to see if `$query1` is returning what you expect. If so, then there's nothing in the code that follows to prevent this from functioning as you described in your question.

If `$query1` is returning something *unexpected*, then I'd start there by rebuilding the query.